# Shopware 6 App | How to translate custom fields

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

We build an app and want a snippet / translation for Shopware 6 custom fields (https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/custom-data/custom-fields)

Is it possible to add a translation text for every category?

```xml
<custom-fields>
        <custom-field-set>
            <name>minds_show_category_discount</name>
            <label>Show Discount</label>
            <label lang="de-DE">Rabatt anzeigen</label>
            <related-entities>
                <category />
            </related-entities>
            <fields>
                <bool name="minds_scd_category_enabled">
                    <label>Show discount</label>
                    <label lang="de-DE">Rabatt anzeigen</label>
                    <position>1</position>
                </bool>

                <!-- Here I would like to input a text that is translatable -->
            </fields>
        </custom-field-set>
    </custom-fields>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no plain text element to use in custom fields. As the name suggests the elements are types of different inputs, dropdowns, checkboxes and so on. If you want to add a descriptive text to one of those UI elements you can use the `help-text` property, which is also translatable.

```xml
<label>Lorem</label>
<label lang="de-DE">Ipsum</label>
<help-text>Lorem</help-text>
<help-text lang="de-DE">Ipsum</help-text>
```

All translations for labels and help-texts etc will be the same across all categories and can't be different on a category-by-category level if that is what you meant.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I didn't want to translate the title / help text of the input box but the content. So that the admin user can customize it per language.

Comment: The custom fields of categories are translatable by default. Just change the language in the dropdown next to the Cancel/Save buttons when you're editing a category and you can enter differing values for each language. If there's no differing value provided for a language it will be inherited from the default language, which is set during the initial installation of Shopware.